# Exception while recording Audio

Tags: c#, xna, naudio

I tried to record mic from NAudio , XNA but when I open & play any video in VLC or start calling in Skype,

> recording app terminates with
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x6E0DCF9D (clr.dll) in WinRecord.exe:  Stack
>   cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.
>
> OR
>
> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

I am actually trying to record VOIP conversation. App works fine if i dont start VLC or Skype

Here is code (NAudio):

```
    WaveIn mic = null;
    WaveFileWriter waveFile = null;

    public Record(string savefilepath)
    {
        mic = new WaveIn();
        mic.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);
        mic.DataAvailable += mic_DataAvailable;
        mic.RecordingStopped += mic_RecordingStopped;
        waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(savefilepath, mic.WaveFormat);
    }


    public void start()
    {
        mic.StartRecording();
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        mic.StopRecording();
    }

    void mic_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        if (waveFile != null)
        {
            waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            waveFile.Flush();
        }
    }

    void mic_RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mic != null)
        {
            mic.Dispose();
            mic = null;
        }

        if (waveFile != null)
        {
            waveFile.Close();
            waveFile.Dispose();
            waveFile = null;
        }
    }
```

Same happens with XNA. I am on Windows 8 64bit & code compiled for .net 4,laptop has internal mic.

Another Question: while recording VOIP app i need to record speakers too, how can i record both side conversation? Any clue or link to sample code?

Comment: look at WasapiLoopbackCapture to capture audio that is being played. Your other problem sounds like a soundcard driver issue.

Comment: @MarkHeath I tried to fallback to default driver's ( window's default driver )  still same issue. Clear me if I am wrong: Any no of applications simultaneously use mic, record mic. Is this right?. ( Means i can record skype conversation )

Comment: No, to record skype conversation you need to use Desktop API (Skype4COM). Sadly this API is being phased out

Comment: Problem resolved, It was driver issue, I am now recording mic & speaker, i want to save them to one wave file means I want to merge audio to one conversation ( full duplex talk ), any hints?

Comment: Use MixingSampleProvider